# Remover un href con jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, pug

Hola tengo un tabla la cual envia arobacion a un usuario , al apretar el boton me abre un modal , dentro de este modal se encuentra el usuario a seleccionar y el boton enviar , lo que quiero realizar es que al precioanr el boton enviar desaparezca el botón que abre el modal .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este en mi boton que abre el modal :

```
 .col-3.p-5.border-bottom.border-right.border-plomo.text-vecc.font-weight-bold Aprobación
                        .col-4.p-5.border-bottom.border-right.border-plomo
                                span#nAprobacionDet
                                a(href="#modal-aprobacion" ,id="map",class="btn btn-primary", data-toggle='modal') Enviar Aprobacion
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es mi modal :

```
    #modal-aprobacion.modal.fade
    .modal-dialog
        .modal-content
            form#formEnvioAprobacion
                .modal-header
                    h4.modal-title Envío de Requerimiento a Aprobación: 
                    button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='modal', aria-hidden='true') ×
                .modal-body
                    .row.no-gutters
                        .col-4.p-5.border-right.border-bottom Responsable
                        .col-8.p-5.border-right.border-bottom
                            select.default-select2.w-100#slcAprobacion(name="slcAprobacion", style="width:100%;")

                        .col-4.p-5.border-right.border-bottom Ventajas
                        .col-8.p-5.border-right.border-bottom
                            input.form-control(name="txtVentaja")

                        .col-4.p-5.border-right.border-bottom Desventajas
                        .col-8.p-5.border-right.border-bottom
                            input.form-control(name="txtDesventaja")

                .modal-footer
                    a.btn.btn-white(href='#', data-dismiss='modal') Cerrar
                    //a.btn.btn-white(href='#', data-dismiss='modal') Resetear
                    input.btn.btn-primary(type="submit", value="Enviar Aprobacion")
```

Jquery que envia formulario:

```
$("#formEnvioAprobacion").submit(function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault(event);
    let formData=new FormData($(this)[0]);
    formData.append("idRequerimiento", idReq);

    ajaxDinamicoForm("mesa_ayuda/asignarResponsableAprob",formData, function(data)
    {
        if(data.recepcion)
        {
            if(data.estado==="success")
            {
                cargarAprobacion(idReq);
                cargarHistorialReq(idReq);
                $("#modal-aprobacion").modal("toggle");

            }
            else
            {
                alert(data.estado+" - "+data.msj);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `$("#map").removeAttr("href");`

Comment: ¿Pero quiere desaparecer el botón del modal o solo el href? si es el href está ok la respuesta, si es lo otro $('a#modal-aprobacion').remove()

Answer (score 0):

Para eliminar el anchor es con removeAttr pero si quieres eliminar el boton en sí

```js
$(function(){
  $('a#modal-aprobacion').remove()
})
```

```css
a{
background: #eee;
color: #333;
display: inline-block;
padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" id="#modal-aprobacion">Abrir modal</a>
```

Comment: ESta es mi linea de codigo en el DOM la que abre el modal                                    a(href="#modal-aprobacion" ,id="#modal-aprobacion",class="btn btn-primary", data-toggle='modal') y la intento cerrar con $(function(){
  $('a#modal-aprobacion').remove()
}) pero no sucede nada , el boton de enviar aprobación no desaparece

Comment: Eso es por que tu ID es id="#modal-aprobacion" y debe ser id="modal-aprobacion" sin la almohadilla(#). los id's ya se llaman de por sí con la almohadilla pero no la llevan en el nombre original. :)